# How do you get a user avatar from a mentioned with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i made an avatar command for my bot but it doest work with mentioions, im trying to not use ' @client.command ' because it causes problems for the rest of the code

```
  if message.content.startswith('+avatar'):
        sender = message.author
        name = sender.display_name
        avatar_url = sender.avatar_url

        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="**{}**".format(sender), description="Username: {}".format(name), color=0xec9e36)
        embedVar.set_image(url = avatar_url)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

is what i have written and i cant find any ways of making it work, any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: What type of client are you using? `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot`?

Comment: `discord.Client` @12944qwerty

Comment: What's your reasoning for not using `commands.Bot` and the commands version instead?

Comment: The rewrite version of dpy makes commands really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to do something like
`+avatar @mention`
A mention is basically a string marking that contains ID of the user.

```py
import re

def is_mention(s):
    '''Check if the string is a valid 'mention' string for Discord'''
    try:
        return bool(re.match(r'<@!?(\d+)>', s))
    except Exception:
        return None


def mention_to_id(s):
    '''Extract user-id from the mention'''
    if is_mention(s):
        return int(re.sub(r'[<>!@]', '', s))
    return None
```

You can first extract the mention string using `mention_str = message.content.split()[1]`, and then call `mention_to_id` function to extract the ID from mention string.

After that, call `get_user` on your bot (client) object to get the user, which will return a `User` object which has `avatar_url` field.

To summarize,

```py
if message.content.startswith('+avatar'):
    message_parts = message.content.split()
    if len(message_parts) > 1:
        mention_str = message.content.split()[1]
        if is_mention(mention_str):
            user = client.get_user(mention_to_id(mention_str)
            # do whatever with user.avatar_url
        else:
            # Warn about invalid mention
     else:
         # Whatever you want to do when there's no mention
```

References:

1. `get_user`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user
2. `User`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User

Answer (score 0):

I used `message.mentions` to find if someone is mentioned in the message and if mentioned i took `the mentioned user's` *name* and *avatar_url* else i took the `sender's` *name* and *avatar_url*

```
  if message.content.startswith('+avatar'):

        if( len(message.mentions) > 0 ):   #checking if someone is mentioned

            #mesage.mentions[0] is the first mentioned user in the message
            name = message.mentions[0].display_name
            avatar_url = message.mentions[0].avatar_url

        else: #no one is mentioned

            name = sender.display_name
            avatar_url = sender.avatar_url

    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Username: {}".format(name), color=0xec9e36)
    embedVar.set_image(url = avatar_url)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```